# Cassandra cluster - Migrating all hosts in cluster

Tags: cassandra

I am using Cassandra(3.5) with 20 nodes with data center-1 with 10 nodes and data center-2 with 10 nodes and has huge data. All hosts belong to say legacy hosts. Now we have newer generation hosts say generation-2.

I have tried adding new nodes and decommissioning old node. But this will be tie consuming.

Q1: How can I migrate all hosts from legacy hosts to generation-2 host? What is the best approach for that?

 Q2: What will be rollback strategy?

 Q3: Finally, How can I validate data once I migrate to generation-2 hosts?

Comment: the number of nodes in DCs is the same?

Answer (score 0):

If you just replacing the nodes with newer hardware, keeping the same number of nodes, then it's simple (operations should be done on every node):

1. prepare the new installation on every node, with configuration identical to existing nodes, but with different IP addresses but don't start the nodes
2. (optional) disable autocompaction with `nodetool disableautocompaction` - this could help to execute step 5 faster
3. copy data from old node to new node using `rsync` (this could take long time)
4. execute `nodetool drain` & stop old node
5. use `rsync` to synchronize changes happened since initial copying (it should be relatively fast)
6. make sure that the old node won't start again (for example, remove Cassandra package) - otherwise it could be a chaos
7. start the new node

This works because Cassandra node is identified by the UUID that is stored in the local table, so changing of IP doesn't affect the operations.

P.S. In future, if you'll need to replace node (not as described, but completely died), use the [procedure of node replacement](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsReplaceNode.html) - in this case, you won't stream data twice, as happened when you do decomissioning and then re-adding node.

Comment: Thanks Alex...Q: What will be rollback strategy?
Q: How can I validate data once I migrate ?

Comment: why do you need to rollback? It's just a hardware change, not upgrade of the version... Similarly for validation - you need to run repairs after migration (you may need to run it after upgrade of every node, if the steps 4-7 will take more than 3 hours).