# Can I upgrade a Cassandra cluster swapping in new nodes running the updated version?

Tags: cassandra, upgrade, cassandra-3.0, operation

I am relatively new to Cassandra... both as a User and as an Operator. Not what I was hired for, but it's now on my plate. If there's an obvious answer or detail I'm missing, I'll be more than happy to provide it... just let me know!

---

I am unable to find any recent or concrete documentation that explicitly spells out how tolerant Cassandra nodes will be when a node with a higher Cassandra version is introduced to an existing cluster.

Hypothetically, let's say I have 4 nodes in a cluster running 3.0.16 and I wanted to upgrade the cluster to 3.0.24 (the latest version as of posting; 2021-04-19).  For reasons that are not important here, *running an 'in-place' upgrade on each existing node is not possible*. That is: I can not simply stop Cassandra on the existing nodes and then do an `nodetool drain; service cassandra stop; apt upgrade cassandra; service cassandra start`.

I've looked at the [change log](https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/cassandra-3.0/CHANGES.txt) between 3.0.17 and 3.0.24 (inclusive) and don't see anything that looks like a major breaking change w/r/t the transport protocol.

So **my question is**: Can I introduce new nodes (running `3.0.24`) to the c* cluster (comprised of `3.0.16` nodes) and then run `nodetool decommission` on each of the `3.0.16` nodes to perform a "one for one" [replacement](https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra-oss/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsReplaceLiveNode.html) to upgrade the cluster?

Do i risk any data integrity issues with this procedure? Is there a specific reason why the procedure outlined above wouldn't work? What about if the number of tokens each node was responsible for was increased with the new nodes? E.G.: `0.16` nodes equally split the keyspace over `128` tokens but the new nodes `0.24` will split everything across `256` tokens.

**EDIT**: After some back/forth on the `#cassandra` channel on the apache slack, it appears as though there's no issue w/ the procedure. There were some other comorbid issues caused by other bits of automation that *did* threaten the data-integrity of the cluster, however.  In short, *each new node* was adding ITSSELF to list list of `seed` nodes *as well*. This can be seen in the logs: `This node will not auto bootstrap because it is configured to be a seed node.`

Each new node failed to bootstrap, but did not fail to take new writes.

**EDIT2:** I am *not* on a k8s environment; this is 'basic' EC2. Likewise, the volume of data / node size is quite small; ranging from tens of megabytes to a few hundred gigs in production. In all cases, the cluster is fewer than 10 nodes. The case I outlined above was for a test/dev cluster which is normally 2 nodes in two distinct rack/AZs for a total of 4 nodes in the cluster.

Answer (score 2):

Running bootstrap & decommission will take quite a long time, especially if you have a lot of data - you will stream all data twice, and this will increase load onto cluster.  The simpler solution would be to replace old nodes by copying their data onto new nodes that have the same configuration as old nodes, but with different IP and with 3.0.24 (don't start that node!).  Step-by-step instructions are in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62191756/cassandra-cluster-migrating-all-hosts-in-cluster/62193339#62193339), when it's done correctly you will have minimal downtime, and won't need to wait for bootstrap decommission.

Another possibility if you can't stop running node is to add all new nodes as a [new datacenter](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html), adjust replication factor to add it, use `nodetool rebuild` to force copying of the data to new DC, switch application to new data center, and then [decommission the whole data center](https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/5.1/dse-admin/datastax_enterprise/operations/opsDecomissionDC.html) without streaming the data.  In this scenario you will stream data only once.  Also, it will play better if new nodes will have different number of `num_tokens` - it's not recommended to have different num_tokens on the nodes of the same DC.

P.S. usually it's not recommended to do changes in cluster topology when you have nodes of different versions, but maybe it could be ok for 3.0.16 -> 3.0.24.

Comment: Thanks! Copying the EBS volume to a new node was considered, but I was operationally uncertain about the repercussions of changing the node IP/ID _and_ version at the same time. I need as little downtime as possible for this, so the naïve approach of 2x the size of the cluster seemed like an easier way to achieve. 

Do you have any pointers to where in the documentation adjusting the `num_tokens` is discouraged? I have a vague recollection of reading something along the lines of "..allows for tuning based on node resources .." which didn't sound like an outright "hey... don't do this!"

Comment: In some cases it's doable, but you just need to understand that the node with `2xN` tokens may need to have more resources than node with `N` tokens - because it will store more data and handle 2x more requests... And this increase in the requests may lead to longer response times and increased load onto the nodes

Comment: But re-attaching of EBS (I didn't notice this update) to the new node should be possible, even with the new version of Cassandra on it. And it would be faster than adding new DC. Also, if you can reattach EBS, why you can't do `apt-get upgrade cassandra`? Regarding IP - nodes in Cassandra are identified by UUID created when they are initialized, that's why copying of existing data (all data) allows to do the upgrades of hardware

Comment: Thanks for clarifying, @alex. I have increased / plan to increase the node's hardware / size to compensate for the change in `num_tokens`. I found `CASSANDRA-13701` and am reading through it now trying to understand why 256 isn't ideal.

I can't `apt upgrade` because the existing/legacy nodes are a dumpster-fire. They are using ephemeral volumes and Cassandra was installed manually (`wget` the tar file, extract...) and have some other "bespoke" things that I want to phase out.

Comment: I can attach an EBS vol to the existing nodes, copy the data over, adjust `fstab` and restart c* for now. Then, to upgrade the node, I can stop a legacy node, move the EBS volume over to the new node but this has will create some additional issues w/ the terraform that provisions the nodes in the c* cluster that won't be trivial to work around.

I was hoping for a simpler procedure where c* itself would take care of data redistribution once additional compute instances have been introduced to the cluster. To save me the trouble of hacking around in the legacy terraform monolith.

Answer (score 1):

To echo Alex's answer, 3.0.16 and 3.0.24 still use the same SSTable file format, so the complexity of the upgrade decreases dramatically.  They'll still be able to stream data between the different versions, so your idea should work.  If you're in a K8s-like environment, it might just be easier to redeploy with the new version and attach the old volumes to the replacement instances.

"What about if the number of tokens each node was responsible for was increased with the new nodes? E.G.: 0.16 nodes equally split the keyspace over 128 tokens but the new nodes 0.24 will split everything across 256 tokens."

A couple of points jump out at me about this one.

First of all, it is widely recognized by the community that the default `num_tokens` value of 256 is waaaaaay too high.  Even 128 is too high.  I would recommend something along the lines of 12 to 24 (we use 16).

I would definitely *not* increase it.

Secondly, *changing* `num_tokens` requires a data reload.  The reason, is that the token ranges change, and thus each node's responsibility for specific data changes.  I have changed this before by standing up a new, logical data center, and then switching over to it.  But I would recommend *not* changing that if at all possible.

"In short, each new node was adding ITSSELF to list list of seed nodes as well."

So, while that's not recommended (every node a seed node), it's not a show-stopper.  You can certainly run a nodetool repair/rebuild afterward to stream data to them.  But yes, if you can get to the bottom of why each node is adding itself to the seed list, that would be ideal.

Comment: Thanks! The cluster is small (both node count and data size). I need this procedure to be w/ as little downtime as possible for when it's done in production. That's why mounting the ebs volume to a new instance was quickly abandoned.

I was not aware that changing the `num_tokens` would require a data re-load... although that would certainly explain some lost data. Can you point to documentation that spells out that this is necessary / why it can only be set at cluster creation? Likewise, thank you for the tip about the default `num_tokens`.